# Customize ActiveAdmin Page based on Roles

Tags: activeadmin

How can we customize an ActiveAdmin page for different users based on their role:

```
ActiveAdmin.register_page 'Dashboard' do
  content title: 'Admin Content' do
    # show this only to admins
  end

  content title: 'Reviewer Content' do
    # show this only to reviewers
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying several complicated things, the solution was straightforward:

```
ActiveAdmin.register_page 'Dashboard' do
  menu priority: 1, label: proc { I18n.t('active_admin.dashboard') }

  content title: proc { I18n.t('active_admin.dashboard') } do
    render partial: current_user.admin? ? 'admin_dashboard' : 'content_dashboard'
  end
end
```

Then you can render those partials based on roles.